# r MatchIt output: cannot see first output showing mean match data

Tags: r, printing, output, matching

because the output of matchit in the console shows so much data, I am unable to see what is at the top of the output where the match improvement data is. I increased my maxprint but it still isn't enough. Is there a way to ask to see the first 100 rows of the console output? Or is there a matchit command that will produce just the summary stats?

Comment: Is `head` an option?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work for this. I am wondering if maybe there is a workaround with something like capture.output or similar?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it's the best way but it seems to have worked:

```
df2 <- capture.output(df1)
writeLines(df2, "outfile.txt")
```